# Trying a single Neo4j Cypher query for my graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have "users" who owns "items", users are also friends w/ each other. I am trying to construct a cypher query to return all items I own PLUS those my friends own in a single query. I can do them individually but can't figure out how to do it in a single query.

RELATIONSHIPS:

```
(u:user)-[:OWNS]-(i:items)
(u:user)-[:FRIEND]-(f:user)
```

Let's say I have just two users in my DB and 100 items. Out of 100, the first person owns (1-5) 5 items and the 2nd person owns another 5 items(6-10). These two users are also friends.

I get 5 items  if I do:

```
MATCH (uer1)-[:OWNS]->(i:items) return i
```

I get another 5 items if I do:

```
MATCH (uer1)-[:FRIEND]->(f)-[:OWNS]->(i:items) return i
```

But I need to combine them both for a given user(user1) so I can return all 10 items in a single shot. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two (or more options)

#### Union

```
MATCH (user:User {name:"Raja"})-[:OWNS]->(i:Item) return i
UNION
MATCH (user:User {name:"Raja"})-[:FRIEND]->(f)-[:OWNS]->(i:Item) return i
```

#### Variable length paths

```
MATCH (user:User {name:"Raja"})-[:FRIEND*0..1]->(f)-[:OWNS]->(i:Item) return i
```

in this case we look at friends of the distance 0 (the user itself) to one (first degree friends)

The first option might be faster
The second is more versatile.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Both answers are great! 2.2 browser doesn't show time-taken anymore so not sure which one is faster.